# Magento2: How to check template name

Tags: magento2, template

I want to check template name for this website:
https://sportofino.com/

I try to find in source skin but cannot find. Anyone help?

Comment: It looks ,like they have custom template `Snowdog_sportofino` https://unsee.cc/f3c0b1da/

Comment: Image from this link no work. Can you please upload again?

Comment: https://ibb.co/jJPcR7N please check

Comment: Ok thank you. I see this project in on main homepage on snow.dog but they provide extension only without designe. So maybe is available similar template?